# Looking for a centred, full-screen terminal

Tags: terminal, vim, fullscreen

There exist out there several different 'distraction-free editors' for writing: these provide a fullscreen, minimal environment with the goal of forcing oneself to focus on the task at hand.

I want to do something similar with `vim`. While I can simply fire it up in a terminal and then press F11 to put it to fullscreen, I *also* want to limit the width to [around 75 characters](http://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability) and centre the area I'm using.

Think about how word processors provide a virtual page in the middle of the program -- that's what I want. Sort of.

Is there a way to do this, either with a special terminal program or with some setting in vim? If one of the GUI vim programs have this capability, or if there's any other way of doing it that I haven't thought of, that would also be a useful answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you start `screen` in a maximized `xterm` (<kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd> in `xterm`) as:

```
screen -c this-file
```

Where `this-file` contains:

```
focusminsize 75 25
split -v
focus
only
split -v
split -v
focus
```

You'll get a center region of width `75`.

Comment: This is *so close* to perfect, thanks. This puts up white borders around the active area and along the bottom of the terminal; do you know if there's a way to get rid of those?

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: RE: my previous comment, the answer to getting rid of the borders can be found [at this SU question](http://superuser.com/questions/506080/screen-divider-border-width-and-color/627756?noredirect=1#627756). I put the lines in my `.screenrc`, so my default `screen` will use all the commands here. Works perfectly for me on Ubuntu 13.04, `gnome-terminal` version 3.6.1 (and on xterm and guake) and `screen` version 4.00.03jw4. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on Fedora 14 and gnome-terminal version 2.32.0. Screen version 4.00.03. `xterm -v`, 6.8.99.903. Doesn't work there.

Comment: Tried it on Ubuntu 13.04 worked there. I now see what it's doing. It's 3 panes, split equally, and the focus is in the middle one.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a program such as `devilspie` to accomplish this. In case you've never heard of `devilspie`:

*excerpt*

> A window-matching utility, inspired by Sawfish's “Matched Windows”
>   option and the lack of the functionality in Metacity. Metacity lacking
>   window matching is not a bad thing — Metacity is a lean window
>   manager, and window matching does not have to be a window manager
>   task.
>
> Devil's Pie can be configured to detect windows as they are created,
>   and match the window to a set of rules. If the window matches the
>   rules, it can perform a series of actions on that window. For example,
>   I can make all windows created by X-Chat appear on all workspaces, and
>   the main Gkrellm1 window does not appear in the pager or task list.

It should be in most distros' repos.

#### Example

So to center a `xterm` window running `vim` inside of it you'd do the following.

1. Make your Devil's Pie config. dir.

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/.devilspie
   ```
2. Create a `.ds` file specifying you're Devil's Pie rule

   ```
   $ cat ~/.devilspie/something.ds 
   (if
       (matches (application_name) "vim")
       (begin
           (geometry "600x400")
           (center)
       )
   )
   ```
3. Run `devilspie`. I like to run it debug mode (`-d`) to start.

   ```
   $ devilspie -d
   Devil's Pie 0.22 starting...
   Loading /etc/devilspie
   /etc/devilspie doesn't exist
   Loading /home/saml/.devilspie
   Loading /home/saml/.devilspie/something.ds
   1 s-expressions loaded.
   ```
4. Run our `xterm` with `vim`.

   ```
   $ xterm -e vim
   ```

[image: ss of xterm vim]

#### What's my window's name?

You can use the command `xlsclient -l` to get a list of open windows. I find it the easiest way to determine a window's name for incorporation into `devilspie`. You might also want to make use of `xwininfo` too.

#### Example

```
$ xlsclients -l|less
...
Window 0x6800023:
  Machine:  grinchy
  Name:  vim
  Icon Name:  vim
  Command:  xterm -e vim
  Instance/Class:  xterm/XTerm
...
```

You can control a windows name like this:

```
$ xterm -title WeirdWindow -e vim
```

#### References

- [Devilspie - Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)
- [Devil's Pie - GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/DevilsPie)
- [Devil's Pie - burtonini.com](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie)
- [Devil's Pie documentation - foosel.org](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie)

Comment: This is definitely neat, but it isn't what I'm trying to accomplish. It just positions the window in a specified place & with specified window dimensions, right? I want to have an active 'page' in the centre of the screen, with the rest of the screen blank -- so there are no distractions in the background.

Comment: @evilsoup - yes it centers xterm @ specified dimensions. You can blank the background, I'll update my answer just so we have an alternative method. Your question didn't say you wanted it blanked in the background, maybe I missed something. Also I think you're missing the power of `devilspie`. You could add a rule to the .ds file to minimize everything else, for example.

Comment: @evilsoup - would blanking out the background suffice? I know you've got the other solution but I just wanted to provide an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for Vim called [VimRoom](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/) which provides this via a mapping (default is V).